# Get a list of all s3 exported methods from a package

Tags: r

I am writing a package and would like to get a list of all exported s3 methods. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you looked at [`.S3methods`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/methods.html)? You'll need to be looking for something (not just all), but for instance `.S3methods(class="data.frame")` returns all current methods that advertise a `data.frame`-specific function.